# Marketing Cloud Engagement Split Email Clicks

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

Are link clicks trackable if they contain an AmpScript field in them? (within Journey Builder)

Currently have a URL that looks like this:
*https://teamlocker.squadlocker.com/#/lockers/%%SL_Store_Id%%*

When I look at the engagement split and select 'clicks', it doesn't show any of the links that contain AmpScript.

Comment: Also I dont think you are calling the %%SL_Store_ID%% value properly. You should use %%=v(SL_Store_ID)=%%

Comment: Good catch @Data_Kid

Comment: My bad you would have to use the concat Ampscript function to piece them together.

Comment: Basically this:  
<https://teamlocker.squadlocker.com/#/lockers/%%=Concat('begin','SL_Store_Id','end')=%%>

Comment: I meant the url string and the Ampscript variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer** : Yes

**Explanation:**
 Links with ampscript do not show up on the click activity report. To overcome this, you would either have to use [alias tags](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019NG4QAM) or the ImpressionRegion Ampscript (See [Begin Impression Region](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/beginimpressionregion3/#BeginImpressionRegion) & [End Impression Region function](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/endimpressionregion2/) to make these available in your click activity report.

In addition to this, I would advise you place add a redirectTo and a Concat around it like this:

```
%%=redirectTo(Concat('https://teamlocker.squadlocker.com/#/lockers/',@SS_Store_Id))=%%
```

Comment: Without the Begin/End Impression Regions, would that mean that the Flow Control - Engagement Split would not work?  Making it appear that no one has clicked any link with AmpScript in it? @data-kid

Comment: It would work but not show up in reporting

Answer (score 1):

IF your URL will be

> https://www.google.com/conen-AU?email=%%Contact_Value%%&cid=%%CustomerID%%&al=Y&token_required&title=What%20you%20need%20to%20know%20about%20patients%20with%20Type%202%20Diabetes%20and%20established%20CVD&url=https://www.google.com.au/callback/036?isUpnext=false&playlist=false&q=812e2354-ed4f-4f5d-a184-d85315ea04cc&series=false&utm_source=google&utm_medium=Mass%20E-mail&utm_campaign=PLY%20James-%5BAU-TR-NA-NA-VI-LO-EN-2021%5D

Use the Ampscript in the Email:

```
%%[
    SET @URL1 = "https://www.google.com/conen-AU??email="

    SET @Contact_Value = [Contact_Value]

    SET @CustomerID = [CustomerID]

    SET @Final_URL = Concat(@URL1,@Contact_Value,'&cid=',@CustomerID,'&al=Y&token_required&title=What%20you%20need%20to%20know%20about%20patients%20with%20Type%202%20Diabetes%20and%20established%20CVD&url=https://www.google.com.au/callback/036?isUpnext=false&playlist=false&q=812e2354-ed4f-4f5d-a184-d85315ea04cc&series=false&utm_source=google&utm_medium=Mass%20E-mail&utm_campaign=PLY%20James-%5BAU-TR-NA-NA-VI-LO-EN-2021%5D')

]%%

href="RedirectTo(@Final_URL)"
```