# Links not showing up for Engagement Split in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We'd like to exclude members from our Journey once they click on a specific link.  The link is very much in the email, but it doesn't appear as a selection within the available links for an Engagement Split.

The link does have a variable - email address - at the end of it.

I tried to build the URL via concatenation, as was (kind of) suggested here, and while the URL works (as it did before), we still do not see it as an option to select

Two versions of the link we've tried:

```
%%=RedirectTo(Concat('https://www.site.com/on/demandware.store/Site/default/confirm-opt?email=',@email))=%%
```

and

```
https://www.site.com/on/demandware.store/Site/default/confirm-opt?email=%%emailaddr%%
```

I should add - the URL appears fine when %%emailaddr%% is removed... but, this is an essential part of the URL. Is there a workaround?

Comment: A 100% complete guess, but have you tried adding an alias to the a tag? I believe the issue is that SFMC is not recognizing it as a valid link, so is not including it on the list. Having an alias may help get past this boundary by placing a defined name on the link.

Comment: If you meant adding alias="some value", then that did not work.

Comment: drat! of course it couldn't be an easy fix!

Comment: I think the engagement splits only work with static links.

Comment: There is a limitation with engagement splits where links that use either AmpScript or have parameters in the URL are not recognized. I'm not sure why this is the case but it has been like this since the engagement split was introduced. I hope SFMC is working on a fix because it is a huge limitation. See the 'notes' in blue in the documentation linked below for reference. http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/use_the_engagement_split_activity/

Comment: Thank you Mark for pointing out the documentation on that (and Adam for stating the same just before).  Thankfully, I have a "workaround" in that the link click changes a value in the DE, which ultimately is the grand prize we're looking for.

Hopefully we can get this resolved ASAP as I think this is a big miss.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeRosedale - just come across the same issue, good to know about the static link requirement. 
Was the workaround running a query based on the URL clicked by the subscribers, to be flagged as TRUE? Or was there a simpler way to go about it? 
Trying to minimize the amount of flag queries on each data extension, but if it's the only resort - alrighty.

Comment: If you're looking to create an Engagement split, then it's not feasible to do so with a dynamic link.  You can do it if ANY click is made in the email.  If you simply want to exclude clickers from receiving the next email, I would suggest trying a SQL query on the URL and using the resultant Data Extension as an Exclusion

Comment: Thanks for the response @GeorgeRosedale - tried all the above and even the solution suggested here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179785/marketing-cloud-engagement-split-email-clicks
But to no avail. Will be given the Data Extension flags a go to update the contacts with a 'link clicked' boolean flag to decide the engagement split for the next day.

Comment: Not sure if anyone tested this themselves, but wanted to confirm that JB still detects the click even for AmpScript URLs. I wrapped mine in RedirectTo